# After a 90-days stay at France within 180 days, can I still visit Croatia?

Tags: schengen, croatia, 90-180-visa-rules

I have heard the 90 days limit in Croatia is counted separately and am not sure if it is true. Where can I find the official description?

Comment: Croatia is still not in schengen. Please establish your nationality?

Comment: I am Hong Kong citizen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Staying in Croatia does indeed not count towards your Schengen stay.

[Official source](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/border-crossing/docs/short_stay_schengen_calculator_user_manual_en.pdf):

> Stays in Bulgaria, Croatia, Ireland, Romania, Cyprus and the United
>   Kingdom shall not be taken into account as they are not (yet) part of
>   the Schengen area without internal borders.

Croatia has its own 90 out of 180 rule, as can be read on [this website](http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/) of their Ministry of Foreign and European Affairs. Holder of a valid Schengen visa do not need to apply separately.

Note that Croatia intends to apply for joining the Schengen area in 2015. Depending on the outcome and how soon your journey is, this should be taken into account.

Comment: “hopes” might be more accurate than “intends”, as Bulgaria and Romania demonstrate, it's not entirely under their control.

Comment: @Relaxed "intends" no more implies control than "hopes".

Comment: @phoog I think it does, what Croatia intends to do is apply to join, not join. Besides, it's kind of relevant for prospective travelers to know that this process is highly uncertain in the current context and I think that “hopes” conveys that too.

Comment: I changed the last paragraph to better reflect the uncertainty here.

Answer (score 3):

The HKSAR passport allows 90 days stay in Croatia, as per the HK Immigration website: http://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/service/travel_document/visa_free_access.html

Please also refer to this document for information specific to countries: http://www.immd.gov.hk/pdf/Full_List_of_Visa-free_Access_or_Visa-on-arrival_for_HKSAR_Passport_en.pdf